# How to use two access data sources in word mailmerge

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, mail-merge

I want to design a mailmerge in such a way that the first data source(access query) provides the customer name and number while the second data source (another access query) provides the customers transactions.

The first data source should serve as the filter criterion for the second data source as the second data source has transactions for different customers.

I dont know how to go about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out-of-the-box, Word MailMerge does not actually support multiple data sources in a MailMerge.

That leaves you with two possibilites:

1. code a solution in VBA or some other language
2. Use a DATABASE field to insert the transactions.

I'm not going to try to cover (1) but you may be able to use (2).

(2) has a number of difficulties but this is how it works:

You use the first data source (the one that provides your customer name and number) as the Mail Merge Data Source - set it up in the usual way. As a test, insert some MERGEFIELD fields from your data source, including { MERGEFIELD Id }

You then insert a { DATABASE } field that contains a SQL Query that retrieves the transaction for that customer. The result of that query is a Word table that you can format in a fairly limited way using field code switches. Either that layout will be enough for your purposes or it won't. If it isn't, you will need to postprocess the output (e.g. with VBA) to apply the formatting you want.

For example, suppose your database is located at `c:\mydbs\mydb.accdb`, your first query has a numeric field called `Id`, your second query is called called `transactions_per_customer`, that you have a customer with `Id = 12345` and that you can retrieve the transactions for that customer using

```
SELECT * FROM transactions_per_customer WHERE Id = 12345
```

Then, initially in your Word document, use ctrl-F9 to insert a pair of the special field code braces

```
{  }
```

Between them, type

```
DATABASE \d "c:\\mydbs\\mydb.accdb" \s "SELECT * FROM [transactions_per_customer] t WHERE t.Id = 12345" \h
```

so you have

```
{ DATABASE \d "c:\\mydbs\\mydb.accdb" \s "SELECT * FROM [transactions_per_customer] t WHERE t.Id = 12345" \h }
```

Select the field, use F9 to update it and Alt-F9 to toggle to the field results. With any luck, you will see a table with a heading row (that's what the `\h` does) and some rows of data.

At this point I would save your mail merge main document and do a test run of the merge, merging to a new document, just to verify that *some* database results appear for each customer (they obviously won't be the correct ones). If you can have enough transactions that they will spill over onto more than one page, I suggest you select an Id that lets you tes what happens, because you may find that the table formatting does not behave as you might hope after the first page. (NB, there are other switches for applying standard Word table formats, and you may find it useful to try "fixing" the format using the `\*Mergeformat` switch. You can find Microsoft's documentation of the field code switches [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-database-field-04398159-a2c9-463f-bb59-558a87badcbc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Once you've got that working, you need to change the query to filter the records for each customer in the mail merge data source. In this case, you would need:

```
{ DATABASE \d "c:\\mydbs\\mydb.accdb" \s "SELECT * FROM [transactions_per_customer] t WHERE t.Id = { MERGEFIELD Id }" \h }
```

where *all* the {  } are the special field code braces you insert using ctrl-F9.

Save the document again (I suggest this because if you have made an error in the query and try to test it, you will likely end up stepping through every record acknowledging an error, before deciding you have to kill Word, which no-one really likes to do)

Preview the result for a couple of records to make sure the query is behaving (you may have to select and update the field with F9 while previewing), then run a limited test on a number of records. If all goes well, go for it!

Notes:

1. Word seems to insist on "more syntax than you should really need" in the SQL query. I leave you to explore, but the reason I introduce the table alias name t and use t.Id is because otherwise Word tends to confuse the fields in the data source with the fields in the DATABASE field query.
2. It's best if you can use the column names in the Query that you want to use in the table in the output (if any). But you can also list the columns in the query and alias them. Just try to keep the total query character length under 255 (or possibly 512) characters.
3. A lot of samples out there show a `\c` (connection string) parameter in the DATABASE field. You shouldn't need it as long as you are connecting to an ACCDB or MDB using the default connection method, which is OLE DB.
4. You may need to ensure that the case of any field names you use *in the SQL* matches the case used in Access.
5. If the Id is actually a string value, you will need to quote the relevant field, e.g.

   WHERE t.Id = '{ MERGEFIELD Id }'

rather than

```
WHERE t.Id = { MERGEFIELD Id }
```

(That's just normal (Jet) SQL syntax)

6. Jet SQL accepts some non-standard quotation marks around table names that contain spaces etc. Typically Word itself will use backticks. If you prefer double quotation marks, you may need to double them up `""Query1""` or escape them with `\"Query1\"`
7. If no records are returned, no table is inserted. If you want something else. You can either do something like this:

   ```
   { IF "{ DATABASE \d "c:\\mydbs\\mydb.accdb" \s "SELECT * FROM [transactions_per_customer] t WHERE t.Id = { MERGEFIELD Id }" }" <> "

   " "{ DATABASE \d "c:\\mydbs\\mydb.accdb" \s "SELECT * FROM [transactions_per_customer] t WHERE t.Id = { MERGEFIELD Id }" \h }" "No transactions for this customer." }
   ```

(There should be a paragraph mark between the "" after <>, because Word always inserts an extra paragraph mark when it inserts a database, since around Word 2000)

Or IMO the following is a bit simpler - keep the original field, whose result will be blank if there are no records, and add a test of the record count:

```
{ DATABASE \d "c:\\mydbs\\mydb.accdb" \s "SELECT * FROM [transactions_per_customer] t WHERE t.Id = { MERGEFIELD Id }" \h }
{ IF { DATABASE \d "c:\\mydbs\\mydb.accdb" \s "SELECT count(*) FROM [transactions_per_customer] t WHERE t.Id = { MERGEFIELD Id }" } = 0 "No transactions." }
```

Put the two fields on one line if you want to avoid inserting additional paragraph marks.

Comment: I have done as you have explained and the record for each customer can be seen but not until i click `update field` that the transaction for the customer transaction for the id changes to the current one. How do I solve this?

Comment: @firmphem That's the behaviour in preview. If you actually merge to a new document, print or email, Word will generate the correct table for each customer and insert that as the result of the DATABASE field. If you actually need to preview, sorry, that's just what you have to do.

Comment: great but i dont understand what you mean by merging into a new document. Also i f the wouldnt mind if i can get a code snipet to generate the pdf document of the merge.

Comment: @firmphem: when you go to "Finish and merge" you get various choices - "Edit individual documents" means "merge to a new document", which will open in Word. 
 "Print Documents..." means merge to a printer, and so on. If you want to merge to pdf, there are least two ways to do it - merge to a new document, then use Word's save as PDF, or make sure that you have a PDF printer driver such as Microsoft Print to PDF installed, and print to that printer - Windows will ask you for a file name to save the .pdf to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some learning here.

Go to Word. Open Mail Merge. Now go to the Wizard and start working through the steps.  You should have an Access Report or an Excel Sheet that is laid out in the column header format you need (Name Address, City, Postal Code and so on) and rows (data) that you need.

Make a Word document that has fields referring to the Merge data and step through a couple.

You may wish to create a small Excel spreadsheet as proof of concept. Then build your Access Query to Report to match. (I am pretty sure Word Mail Merge does not execute a live Queries for both picks - it looks to a report for its data). So query to report for headers and then see if you can pull transactions via query - that may work.

You need some examples to learn all the above.

I have done Word Mail Merge from Excel (that was created from raw transaction data) and it worked properly and well.

Comment: I know all these. I have a both queries in my Ms access ready. I have always been using one data source but this demands that I use two data sources in one mailmerge word document.

Comment: I have not seen any capability to do that in my travels with Mail Merge.